# Django: Cannot resolve keyword "is_active'' on /accounts/password_reset/

Tags: django

I am trying to implement Django's built-in password reset functionality using my custom User model but I am running into this error when I try to submit an email address at /accounts/password_reset/:

```
FieldError at /accounts/password_reset/
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field. Choices are: ...
```

Exception location:

```
Exception Location: C:\Users\...\.virtualenvs\my_project-IsNTW6sC\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in names_to_path, line 1378
```

*I can provide the full traceback if someone wants to see it but it's reallllly long and it all points to back-end Django files.*

Here is **models.py:**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False, is_active=True):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address.')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password.')

        user = self.model(
                email = self.normalize_email(email)
            )
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admin = is_admin
        user.active = is_active
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True
            )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True,
                is_admin=True
            )
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # USERNAME_field (email) and pw required by default
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex='^[a-z0-9_-]*$',
            message='Usernames can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, and dashes.'
            )
        ])
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    state_or_province = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=all_choices, default='')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    cc_reference = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=False)
    event_list = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=list)

    def _get_username(self):
        username = self.user.email
        return username

    def _get_firstname(self):
        firstname = self.user.email
        return firstname

    def _get_lastname(self):
        lastname = self.user.email
        return lastname

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.username:
            self.username = self._get_username()
            self.first_name = self._get_firstname()
            self.last_name = self._get_lastname()
        super().save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer below, I fixed the password reset issue. However, I am now unable to log my superuser in to the admin page. New User model is as follows. I did not change the UserManager:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # USERNAME_field (email) and pw required by default
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Comment: Did you change the `User` model? If not, shouldn't this be `is_active`, `is_staff`, etc. instead of `active`, `staff`, etc.

Comment: Aw crap looks like my models.py got cut off. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I take it back - only the first line got lost.

Comment: But as far as I can see, you never have set the `model` of the `UserManager` to your new `UserProfile`.

Comment: I'm truthfully not following you. Can you please show me an example/snippet of what you think I need to change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model defines fields `active`, `admin`, and `staff`, instead of `is_admin`, `is_staff`, `is_active`.

Comment: When I change `active` to `is_active` though, I still get the error. Even if I make a new field `is_active`, and then run `manage.py makemigrations`, it only registers that I removed `active`. It doesn't register that I added `is_active`. Is it possible that once you have a User setup, you can't change the model? I don't think I tested it on a completely from-scratch database.

Comment: You've hidden those fields with your property methods. You should delete those.

Comment: Ahh ok. I will try this when I get home!

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! However, it does seem to have broken something else because now my superuser can't log in to the admin page, lol. Any ideas? I made an edit to my original post with the new User model code.

Comment: Did you change the code in the Manager `create_user` method? Otherwise it is still setting `active` and `staff`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have just renamed the field `active` to `is_active` and removed `is_active` @property function.
And then, when I `makemigrations` it asked me that would I want to rename `active` field to `is_active`, and I hit `Y` to make the migration.
Finally, I `migrate` the changes to the database.
It's worked without any error.

Answer (score 1):

In the class `MyUser`, there might be three functions:

```py
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_staff

def is_admin(self):
    return self.is_admin

def is_active(self):
    return self.is_active
```

I believe that the repetition of these names creates a clash.

- If possible, delete `staff` from your custom `User`.
- delete sudsequent function: Not required (Note: Only function, not the object)

```py
   def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active
```

- Rename u/m function (u can call is_admin using is_staff(self):

```py
   def is_staff(self):
       return self.is_admin
```

This will clear the clash and you both problems will be solved.

**Note**: You also have to remove the `createstaffuser()` function from the `MyUserManager` class, and you have to change `admin` and `active` (wherever you used them) to `is_active` and `is_active` respectively. Finally, you have to remove staff from admin, forms and models.

I hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding is_superuser field into user model then migrate changes.

After, create superuser using terminal/cmd and then try logging as superuser agian